# Finding duplicates in a list using recursion?

Tags: java, list, recursion

I'm suppose to find if there is duplicates in a list and return true or false using recursion only (no loops). So if ArrayList of char is used, [a,b,c,d,e] should return false. [a,a,b,c,d] or [a,b,b,c,c,d] should return true. I've tried and tested different ways and it worked for some cases but not all. I changed my code around and this is what I have now. (Has problem at the last if statement)
Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks.

```
    public static <T> boolean duplicate(List<T> list) throws NullPointerException {
        return duplicateHelper(list, list.get(0));
}

public static <T> boolean duplicateHelper(List<T> list, T t){
    if (list == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if(list.isEmpty())
        return false;
    if(list.size() > 1){
        if(t.equals(list.get(1)))
            return true;        
    }
    if(list.size() == 1)
        return false;
    if(!duplicateHelper(list.subList(1,list.size()), t)){
        return  duplicate(list.subList(1,list.size()));
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Problem is if you want to find duplicate you need two elements one that you are passing one from the list so you need to add implementation that way

Comment: When you step through the code in you debugger what do you see goes wrong?

Comment: Why does it evaluate (and return the result of) `duplicate(..)` after `duplicateHelper(..)`? The initial/kickoff method should likely never be called again ..

Comment: @pst `duplicateHelper` looks for a specific elment `t`, `duplicate` looks for the next element in the list

Comment: can you go through and select an answer for your questions? @TKP

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
function recurse(myList, seenList)  
{  
    currentElement =     myList.removeLastElement();
    if(seenList.contains(currentElement)    
     {
        return false;  
      }
    seenList.add(currentElement);   


    return recurse(myList,seenList);
}
```

While I realize this is homework, I tried to make it as straight forward as possible without giving the complete solution.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you change the incoming list and create a new one. This means that you must make a copy of the input list to create one you can safely modify. If memory is not an issue, great.

Comment: @JohnB It being a homework problem, I am going to let OP figure out the joys of the Iterator object and/or the fun of learning recursive logic.

Comment: in the above, `removeLastElement` needs to be replaced with `remove(0)` to use Java's `List` class

Comment: @JohnB As I said before, this is clearly a homework problem, and it is not my job nor anyone's outside of OP's professor/ TA to give the full working program.  Working through my second masters degree now I utilize my professors as often as possible, as being spoon fed doesn't help.

Comment: OK, point taken, +1. However, I would suggest that removing the first element is in general more efficient than the last given that the input list could be a linked list.

Comment: Wow thanks for all the comments. I can't use add or remove since, as John B mentioned, this will be modifying the list. I'm not allowed to use static fields so I can't make a copy (unless there is another way). I've re-written my code using contains method (instead of equals) and I think it's doing what it's suppose to do now. Thanks.

Comment: @TKP a "cheat" is to use a Vector, which is synchronized, or you can look into Iterator

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is assisted by pre and post conditions. Things that are always true at start and finish. What I see is that when you first enter `duplicateHelper`, elements `t` is at position `0` of the passed list. However, when you recurse into `duplicateHelper` the sublist that is passed no longer contains `t` at index `0` but instead contains the element that was previously compared.

Consider passing a sublist from `duplicate` to `duplicateHelper` and moving the comparison check to a not empty else. Add logging statements to figure out where the code goes wrong.

Comment: Logging is not for debugging locally. Debuggers are.

Comment: I've tried passing in sublist to Helper but the problem is when the Helper returned, I don't get the original sublist so I can't look at the next element. Anyway, I got rid of the helper method and re-wrote the code just using the 'duplicate' and it seems to be working now. Thank you.